# Losing focus on an EditText when the virtual keyboard disappears

Tags: android

I have a little problem with some text fields. I want to lose focus on them when I close the virtual keyboard.

Let's say I select a field, I write something in there and than I press back to close the keyboard. In that situation, I want to automatically lose focus on the selected text field.

Here is what I tried so far. The problem is that if I press done(enter) from the the `searchByName`, it switches to the second text field(`searchByZipcode`) right away but the `focusChangeListener` is not applied. It applies only after I close the keyboard.

```
searchByName.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {

            if (hasFocus) {
                v.getLayoutParams().width = 900;
                searchByZipcode.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                searchByDistance.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().width=405;
                searchByZipcode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                searchByDistance.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
        }
    });


    searchByZipcode.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            searchByZipcode.getLayoutParams().width=660;
            searchByName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    });

    searchByZipcode.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    /* When focus is lost check that the text field
    * has valid values.
    */
            if (hasFocus) {
                v.getLayoutParams().width=663;
                searchByName.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                v.getLayoutParams().width=240;
                searchByName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });


    searchByName.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                searchByName.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    searchByZipcode.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                searchByZipcode.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });

    searchByDistance.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View view, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() != KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return false;
            }
            if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
            {
                searchByDistance.clearFocus();
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you can just clear the current focus by doing this:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    View view = getCurrentFocus();
    if (view != null) {
        view.clearFocus();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where should I put this? I forgot to mention that my text fields are in a fragment. I assume i have to use this override function in `MainActivity`, right?

Comment: Yeah, this should be in your activity.

Comment: Hm... I'm not sure if it happened in newer Android version, but the Pixel 3a simulator doesn't have a [back button](https://i.ibb.co/C8Xd97Y/keyboard.png) and `onBackPress()` isn't triggered when I hide it :/